How to make an airplane less bumpy?
Other than the weight (which to my understanding is the number one factor i.e. a heavier airplane will fly more smoothly than a light airplane), which factors of the airplane design make an airplane more or less bumpy?

Similar

When you say weight -- a heavier aircraft is less bumpy, what you're really after is the wing loading.  A heavier aircraft with a smaller wing will be less bumpy.  The bigger the wing, the more susceptible to gusts.
A flexible structure (particularly in the wings) will help as well.  When gusts hit the wings, they will deflect and not transfer those disturbances into the fuselage as much.  Flexible wings act like the suspension on a car.
Some aircraft now use active measures to suppress gusts.  When a gust is detected, an active computer controlled system will deflect control surfaces to dump or increase lift on part of the wing in response to the gust.  These systems not only reduce the bumpiness of the ride for passengers, they can actually reduce the structural limits that the aircraft must be designed to and thereby can allow the engineers to design a lighter wing.
Here are some videos of the gust alleviation system on the 787.
On YouTube
On Facebook

Hey do you have a link or video that explains the computerized control system for gust suppression? I really would like to see it

Here are some ways to reduce bumpiness.

design the plane to fly higher, where the air is less bumpy.

design the plane to fly faster, so it spends less time in a rising or descending air column so its inertia will have a better chance of "clamping" it against perturbations.

design the plane with "springier" wings (i.e., with a more flexible main spar) to help smooth over the bumps.


Regarding this last effect, it is claimed that the M20-series of Mooneys which had a wooden main spar furnished a smoother ride than the later models that had metal spars.
